# code won't populate email

Tags: php, html, forms, post, html-email

created a simple little php code to populate email with email address and info from a textbox on the form. it originally worked when I was calling to the script from a html form, but once I converted my site to PHP it stopped working. Eventually I would like to put this same info into a Database table but right now I would be content just getting the email to work.

When the form is submitted I get the email address from the customer, but I don't get the info from the textbox. here is my code.

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
mail( "sales@sixtoed-design.com", "Service Request", "From: $email",
$message );
header( "Location: http://www.sixtoed-design.com/thankyou.php" );
?>
```

Like I said it is a very simple code and worked fine before I converted my site completely to PHP.
Below is my code for the form if you need it.

```
<form method="POST" action="sendmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40">
  </textarea><br />
  <input name="" type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `var_dump($_POST);` or checked your developer utility of choice to make sure that the `message` field is being posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the mail function wrong. [See the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

The 3rd parameter should be the message and you send from as a header in the 4th parameter, so:

`mail( "sales@sixtoed-design.com", "Service Request", $message,  "From: $email" );`

See [example 2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3144) in the docs

Comment: thanks Ben, made the changes and it worked perfectly, amazing how something so simple can mess up and entire script.